# how to filter date datatype data in informatica using filter transformation?

Tags: informatica

I am trying to filter the records which are of date data type. when I am trying to write the expression it showing error while validating it.

EX: HIREDATE > '12/02/1980'

when I am validating, it is showing error

Comment: The error occurs, because HIREDATE is a date and '12/02/1980'  represents a string. You can't use the > operator on two different data types. Try Samiks answer, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HIREDATE > TO_DATE('12/02/1980','MM/DD/YYYY')`